# Why this custom sum function gives me error

Tags: python, function, sum

I just try to do a sum of n natural number with my own custom function like this.

```
n = int(input("Enter value of n.\n"))
def sumof(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        s = s +  n -i
    if (n - i)<0:
        break
    return s

print(sumof(n))
```

error looks like this.

```
s = s +  n -i
UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment
```

it looks like error because of variable 's'. Then I realise that I didn't assigned that variable. so I assigned it  `s=0`  as a global variable but I am still getting same error.

Please tell me what am I did'nt wrong here.
I am new to python so sorry for silly mistake in my program.
If error come from.

Comment: `so I assigned it s=0 as a global variable`: Where? Also why a global variable? You could define it as a local variable right before the `for` loop.

Comment: Btw there is simply a formula to calculate the sum of first n natural numbers `s = (n ** 2 + n) / 2` which is way faster

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `s` before referencing it.

```
n = int(input("Enter value of n.\n"))
def sumof(n):
    s = 0 # <--- Add this line
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        s = s +  n -i
        if (nthterm - i)<0:
            break
    return s

print(sumof(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

I find these :

- you need to write `s=0` in the first line of `function`
- check `if and break` in `for` like below. *(you can write `break` in `for` or `while` then when arrive to `break` you can exit from `loop`.)*
- ***(where do you define `nthterm`?)***

```
n = int(input("Enter value of n.\n"))
def sumof(n):
    s = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        s = s +  n -i
        # if (nthterm - i)<0:
        #    break
    return s

print(sumof(n))
```

If you want use `variable` in function as `gloabl` write like below:

```
s = 0
def sumof(n):
    global s
    ...
```

Comment: Bro please tell why s giving error even it is a global variable.

Comment: @Matiiss thanks for your comment but I don't think for this answer we need improve code of OP because OP don't want this, If OP ask for this, we will do this.

Comment: @user1740577 well, maybe they just didn't know that there is such a formula, of course, for practicing you can do this, but using a formula makes it so much more efficient, also I think the range should be `range(n + 1)` because you need to add the number itself, anyways the loop is pretty weird, why not simply do `s += i`?

Comment: @Matiiss you can send your answer. but don't make this hard, op wants to find where did he wrong and how to use global. he didn't ask why I don't get right answer or how efficient or pythonic this code.